# Remove cycle/repetition from list python

Tags: python, list, cycle

I have a list of values which might or might not have certain cycles of elements in it.
I have written below code to extract the index and length of values after that which repeats in the list. My problem is that i now have multiple index and length of values which are repeating. How to remove these elements from main list to remove those cycle

```
data = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,5,6,7,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,23,18]
minrun = 1
lendata = len(data)

for runlen in range(minrun, lendata // 2):
    i = 0
    while i < lendata - runlen * 2:
#         print("i",i)
#         print("runlen", runlen)
#         print(lendata - runlen * 2)
        s1 = data[i:i + runlen]
#         print("s1",s1)
        s2 = data[i + runlen:i + runlen * 2]
#         print("s2",s2)
        if s1 == s2:
            print(i, runlen, s1)
            i += runlen 
        else:
            i += 1
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What's your exact definition of a cycle here?

Comment: in the data i shared, values are 1,2,3,1,2,3.. Here it is a cycle/repetition.. i want to keep only one such sequence.. 4,5,6,7 is continously repeating 3 times.. i want to keep it only once

Comment: Is `1, 1, 1` considered a cycle? What's the minimum cycle length you are considering? If you have `1, 2, 1, 2` and then later in the sequence `1, 2, 1, 2, 1`, is the cycle `1, 2, 1` or `1, 2`?

Comment: minimum cycle length is 2. So the idea i want to solve is.. if i have 1,2,1,2.. I want to eliminate 1,2.. the code i have shown checks for different length of lists.. if u run the code it will give different indices.. my issue is, what if the indices overlap.. how to remove it

Comment: Is it possible to assume that cycles are only and only sequential and incremental series?
Can we define the cycles with i, i+1, i+2? Or they might be i, i-1, then i+2?
Can you describe the sequences in a mathematical formula? If so, then you can slice the sequences and then use the slices to make a dictionary. As dictionary keys have to be unique, it only retains the series once. Then we can extract the keys and construct a list.

Comment: From what it sounds like, I think you'd be better off with recursion. Remove any repeated 2-length cycles first, then check 2-cycles again (because the removal of a cycle could create another). Repeat until no more 2-cycles are found. Then move on to 3-cycles. Same thing. Finally, if having checked for `n / 2`-length cycles and finding none, return. Fair warning: I haven't tested this theory. EDIT: actually the removal of any n-cycle could create a repeated cycle, so I think any time you remove a cycle, you'd need to start over at 2-cycles.

Comment: Also how do cycle lengths take precedence? Why would `4, 5, 6, 7` be kept when `4, 5, 6` also repeats, but in your previous comment you said that the `1, 2` would be removed even though `1, 2, 1` was a valid cycle?

Comment: I promise I'm not trying to give you a hard time, it's just that this doesn't strike me as a particularly well-defined problem as things stand.

Comment: Should an n-cycle be removed immediately, or should its location be recorded and only after checking all possible n-cycles in the sequence should it be removed?

Comment: i know the everything sounds fadish.. but il give a simple example and you guys can suggest me an approach.. instead of numbers in lists, lets consider the values as different sequential steps. Ex: in amazon, we navigate from one page to another. Here i want to remove steps/sequence of steps which user is continuously repeating. How to eliminate this?

Comment: I think starting with 2-cycle is not particularly a good idea. If the list goes by ``1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3``, removing 2-cycle would produce ``1, 2, 3, 3``, whereas it should be ``1, 2, 3``

Comment: what if removal of 3-cycle leads to repetation of bigger cycle?

Answer (score 0):

This could work, but I didn't test for other sequence, I only tested it for your example.

```py
data = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,5,6,7,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,23,18]
print(data)

checkindex = []
for j in range(1, len(data)):
    for k in range(len(data)):
        try:
            if data[k] == data[j+k]:
                if j+k not in checkindex:
                    checkindex.append(j+k)  
        except IndexError:
            continue
checkindex = sorted(checkindex)
for i in range(len(checkindex)-1, -1, -1):
    del data[checkindex[i]]
print(data)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 23, 18]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 23, 18]
```

Explanation:

```py
for k in range(len(data)):
    if data[i+k] == data[j+k]:
```

Basically means like this for example for `j=3`:

```
data[0] == data[3+0]: True
data[1] == data[3+1]: True
data[2] == data[3+2]: True
data[3] == data[3+3]: False
```

For every `True`, append `(j+k)` --> if it is not duplicate. I recommend try printing out here and there to understand more, for example:

```py
data = [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,4,5,6,7,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,23,18]
print(data)

checkindex = []
for j in range(1, len(data)):
    for k in range(len(data)):
        try:
            if data[k] == data[j+k]:
                print(j, k, j+k)
                if j+k not in checkindex:
                    checkindex.append(j+k)  
        except IndexError:
            continue
    print(checkindex)
checkindex = sorted(checkindex)
for i in range(len(checkindex)-1, -1, -1):
    del data[checkindex[i]]
print(data)
```

Your output will be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 23, 18]
[]
[]
3 0 3
3 1 4
3 2 5
[3, 4, 5]
4 6 10
4 7 11
4 8 12
4 9 13
4 10 14
4 11 15
4 12 16
4 13 17
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
8 6 14
8 7 15
8 8 16
8 9 17
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
10 14 24
10 15 25
10 16 26
10 17 27
10 18 28
10 19 29
10 20 30
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
14 10 24
14 11 25
14 12 26
14 13 27
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
18 3 21
18 4 22
18 5 23
18 6 24
18 7 25
18 8 26
18 9 27
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 21, 22, 23]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 21, 22, 23]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 21, 22, 23]
21 0 21
21 1 22
21 2 23
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 21, 22, 23]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 21, 22, 23]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 21, 22, 23]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 21, 22, 23]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 21, 22, 23]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 21, 22, 23]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 21, 22, 23]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 21, 22, 23]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 21, 22, 23]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 21, 22, 23]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 21, 22, 23]
[3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 21, 22, 23]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 23, 18]
```

I personally think the print statement helps me understanding more.

Comment: can you please explain the concept inside 'try' clause

Comment: I updated my answer with more explanation. If something is still unclear ask again.